# How can I append text data to a file on a web server using AlamoFire

Tags: swift, alamofire

How can I append a text string to an existing  text file on a web server using AlamoFire from Swift 5?

Comment: First of All: Does that WebServer allows to "modify/replace" the text file? Does it provide an Web API to do so?

Comment: How can I allow this? Is it by changing the Web.config file?